# MVC MultipleModel DropdownlistFor SaveChanges()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

HI i Have a MultipleModel View with CompanyName and EmployeeRange. CompanyName contains names of companies with a Relationship link to EmployeeRange (int) Field.

The Employee Range is basically

- 0-9
- 10-19
- 20-49

I can create and SaveChanges for a new Company Name Field. 
Please help With Saving Selected value from the EmployeeRange DropDownListFor to DB.

Here is the Code

```
    //MultipleModel.cs
     public partial class MultipleModel
    {
        public MultipleModel()
        {
            CompanyEntities = new company();
            EmployeeEntities = new Employee();
        }

        public company CompanyEntities { get; set; }
        public Employee EmployeeEntities { get; set; }

    }

//CompanyController.cs 
[HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult RegisterCompany(MultipleModel model)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //GET VARIBALE FROM DB
                    var addComanyName = db.companies.Add(model.CompanyEntities);


                    //GET VARIABLLE
                    addComanyName.COMPANY_NAME = model.CompanyEntities.COMPANY_NAME;


                    //ADD VARIBALE TO DB
                    db.companies.Add(addComanyName);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("index");
                }


                return View();
            }

//RegisterCompany.cshtml
@model EISystem.Models.MultipleModel

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyEntities, new SelectList(ViewBag.products, "Employees_Range_ID", "Employees_Range"), "Select Number of Employees")
```

?? How Do i view the DropDownListFor so that selected Value can be POST to Controller and later be saved to DB?

Comment: What `DropDownListFor()`? And what property does it bind to. Show your view.

Comment: Sorry its actually a List of Employee Range which i can only view it by a Viewbag   "ViewBag.products = db.Employees.ToList();"

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (which is what `CompanyEntities` is) - you need a property to bind to which is `int` (assuming `Employees_Range_ID` is also `int`)

Comment: Yes Employees_Range_ID is int. This a Multiplemodel View so whats selected must be saved in the company DB(CompanyEntities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another class which is ViewModel for your MultipleModel class.

Like:

```
public class MultipleModelViewModel
{
    public int SelectedProductId { get; set; }

    public List<Products> ProductList{ get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

In a View

```
@model MultipleModelViewModel


                    @using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterCompany", "Company", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedProductId , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProductId, new SelectList(Model.ProductList, "Id", "Name"), "Select Product", new { @class = "form-control " })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control " })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

                        </div>
                        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-success " id="Save-btn">
                          Save
                        </button>
                    }
```

Controller:

```
        //Get
        public ActionResult RegisterCompany()
        {
            var model = new MultipleModelViewModel (){
                   Name = model.Name,
                   Products = db.Products.Select(x=>new {Id=x.Id, Name=x.Name).ToList()
               };

                return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RegisterCompany(MultipleModelViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {  
               var company = new Company(){
                   Name = model.Name,
                   Product = db.Products.Find(model.SelectedProductId)
               };


               db.companies.Add(company);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }


            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Nicee!! So how do i call this class in the View. Wudnt this exclude the initial class?.. Maybe its clear im new to this by now

Comment: See update. Before you send MultipleModelViewModel class to View, you obviously have to init it.

Comment: I cant use the local variable(model) before it is declared. this is in the 1st ActionResult RegisterCompany().

Comment: Why does it say " i cannot use the local variable(model) before it is declared." HERE  "Name = model.Name,"

Comment: Are you doing it like in example? Inside curved bracers. 
var model = new MultipleModelViewModel (){
                   Name = model.Name,
                   Products = db.Products.Select(x=>new {Id=x.Id, Name=x.Name).ToList()
               };

Comment: Dont know what was wrong but no errors are now experienced. Thanx!!